# Unresolved attribute reference 'cfg' for class 'Runattr'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-class

I have declared a class as follows:

```
class Runattr:
    pass

run = Runattr()
run.cfg = 'some str'
```

When I am trying to access run.cfg further in my code, PyCharm gives me the following warning and I am not able to autocomplete run.cfg:

*Unresolved attribute reference 'cfg' for class 'Runattr' Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.*

I am new to using classes. Can someone tell me why I am seeing this warning and can this be modified to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a PyCharm *warning* (not an error!), since it can't figure out whether that class really should have a `cfg` attribute.

Assuming you're using a modern Python version, add an annotation for such a field:

```
class Runattr:
    cfg: str  # denotes there would/could be a string `cfg`

run = Runattr()
run.cfg = 'some str'
```

Classes and instances can nevertheless have any attributes (and heck, you can even do `setattr(run, "oh this is fun", True)` to have an attribute that's not a valid Python identifier), it's just that IDEs can't be infinitely smart about the dynamic nature here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare on a field named cfg

```
class Runattr:
    cfg = ''

run = Runattr()
run.cfg = 'some str'
```

Comment: This will declare a class-level variable called `cfg` that will be an empty string on every instance of Runattr unless otherwise reassigned.

Comment: Thank you @Yehonatan. Will I have to do this for all the attributes I create using the run object? Isn't there a way to create class attributes on the fly without defining them in the class body?

Comment: you can use a dict from var_name (as string) to value, and declare only on this dict